# Beautiful soup not finding table ID

Tags: python, python-3.x, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract some data from a webpage that has multiple tables.  All the tables have an id="name" attribute.  I am using beautiful soup 4 with Python 3.4.1.  My code lopped through the first tables just fine, but on the last one it returns 'None' and I can't figure out why.

The html code for the table info is below and from what I can see, it was not formatted any differently than the other tables that had other id names such as id=Datagrid1

```html
<TR>
<TD vAlign=top>
  <TABLE id=Datagrid7 
  style="FONT-SIZE: smaller; FONT-FAMILY: Verdana; WIDTH: 675px; BORDER-COLLAPSE: collapse" 
  cellSpacing=0 rules=all align=left border=1>
    <TBODY>
```

The python code below returns None, but will work if I change the id to another known id name.

```
table = soup.find('table', id='DataGrid7')  
print(table)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there was typo error in your program  it should be small `'g'`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html="""<TR>
<TD vAlign=top>
  <TABLE id=Datagrid7
  style="FONT-SIZE: smaller; FONT-FAMILY: Verdana; WIDTH: 675px; BORDER-COLLAPSE: collapse"
  cellSpacing=0 rules=all align=left border=1>
    <TBODY>"""

soup=BeautifulSoup(html)


print soup.find('table',id='Datagrid7')

#output <table align="left" border="1" cellspacing="0" id="Datagrid7" rules="all" style="FONT-SIZE: smaller; FONT-FAMILY: Verdana; WIDTH: 675px; BORDER-COLLAPSE: collapse">
<tbody></tbody></table>
```

Comment: Thanks alot, all the other tags had an upper case G, so now I'll have to change it to account for both.

Answer (score 1):

There's a typo in the code.

The id of the table is `Datagrid7`, not `DataGrid7`:

```
table = soup.find('table', id='Datagrid7')
#                                  ^
```